On the use of Chebyshev's inequality for obtaining asymptotic estimate in a proof
For the full context of the problem please refer to the proof of Prediction $3$ in the note: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/01/04/254a-supplement-4-probabilistic-models-and-heuristics-for-the-primes-optional/.
We have a sequence of non-negative random variables $X_n$ that have mean zero and are independent, each of size $O(\log x) = O(x^{o(1)})$. Fix some natural number $x$, it can be seen that
$\displaystyle \mathop{\bf E} (\sum_{2 < n \leq x} X_n)^k = O( x^{k/2+o(1)})$
for any fixed natural number ${k}$. The argument then follows with:

From Chebyshev’s inequality this implies that ${\sum_{2 < n \leq x} X_n = O( x^{1/2+\varepsilon})}$ with probability ${1-O( x^{-k\varepsilon + o(1)})}$.

Question: With the given bound, a direct application of Chebyshev's inequality gives $\displaystyle {\bf P}(|\sum_{2 < n \leq x} X_n - O(x^{1/2 + o(1)})| \geq t) \leq \frac{O(x^{1+o(1)})}{t^2}$ for some threshold $t > 0$. I wonder what value of $t$ is being inserted here and how the given claim follows as it does.
Edit: It turns out that here we are using Chebyshev’s inequality in what is called the “measure-theoretic” form in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Measure-theoretic_statement in order to get more decay in the t parameter (by taking the “p” parameter to be large, here we call it k); the $p=2$ case of Chebyshev’s inequality is too weak for this application.

What is the "size" of a rv?

@VezenBU: The largest of its absolute value.

Fix $k\in\mathbb N$. Chebyshev's inequality tells us that for any integrable and non-negative random variable $X$, and $t>0$,
$$\mathbb P(X\ge t)\le \frac{\mathbb E[X^k]}{t^k}.\tag1 $$
So now let $X:=\sum_{2 < n \leq x} X_n$ and $t:=x^{1/2+\varepsilon}$. We are given that $\mathbb E[X^k]=O( x^{k/2+o(1)})$, so that applying $(1)$ above yields
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X\ge t)&:=\mathbb P\left(\sum_{2 < n \leq x} X_n\ge x^{1/2+\varepsilon}\right)\\
&\le\frac{O( x^{k/2+o(1)})}{x^{k/2+k\varepsilon}}\\
&= O(x^{-k\varepsilon+o(1)})
\end{align}
The above inequality tells us that with probability $1-O(x^{-k\varepsilon+o(1)})$, the quantity $\sum_{2 < n \leq x} X_n$ is bounded by $x^{1/2+\varepsilon}$, which in particular implies that

[...] ${\sum_{2 < n \leq x} X_n = O( x^{1/2+\varepsilon})}$ with probability $1-O(x^{-k\varepsilon+o(1)}) $.

